# IDTExtensibility2 not found on Visual C++ Outlook Add In Creation

Tags: c++, com

I was using the given link for starting creation of a COM Add In for Outlook: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941475.aspx

I've followed the first set of steps, but on building, getting an error that `_IDTExtensibility2` is undefined. I've tried adding MSADDNDR.dll in the project and added it to Additional Dependancies, but it doesnt work.

What do I need to do to do here?